# How to get the last item from every firebase object and put it into an array

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native-firebase

Folks I'm using `React Native Firebase` and I want to achieve as you can see in the attached `ss`[image]

there's **`message`** key and it has threads underneath and each thread have multiple messages.I want to do like I want get last item from every thread and put it into an array.How to achieve.I'm trying to use foreach and not getting my desired result

here is my code

```
 messagesRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        let messsagesFB = [];

        snapshot.forEach(element => {
          messsagesFB = [...messsagesFB, element.val()];
        });
      });
```

I know my code will push every element but i want to push only last item from each thread

Answer (score 0):

For your database reference `messagesRef`, try adding `.orderByKey().limitToLast(1)` for the query, in which case a loop would not be needed.

```
messagesRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).on('value', snapshot => {
   // TODO: Add to array
}
```

There's also always the catch for the last iteration of a jQuery `foreach` loop. In your case, you could simply do:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(element, idx, messagesFB) {
   if (idx === messagesFB.length - 1){ 
       messsagesFB.push(element.val());
   }
});
```